# Save 4 digits after decimal in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, average, mongojs

I have a node.js app that connects and saves to a mongodb collection.

```
    var durations = []
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var start = performance.now();          
        //do stuff
        var end = performance.now();
        durations.push(end - start); 
    }
    var sum, avg = 0;
    if (durations.length)
    {
        sum = durations.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
        avg = sum / durations.length;
    }

    objectToSave.durationAverage = avg;
    console.log(durations);
    console.log(avg);

    //Add the object to the database through Ajax
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/add',
            data:JSON.stringify(objectToSave),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

On the console :

```
    console.log(durations);

    [0.10000000111176632, 0, 0, 0, 0] 

    console.log(avg);

    0.020000000222353265
```

In my collection:

`{ durationAverage : 0 }`

How can i save the value with 4 digits after the decimal from node.js to mongodb?

Thank you

Comment: There is no related to MongoDB but yes related to Javascript, you have to use ```objectToSave.durationAverage = parseFloat(avg.toFixed(4))``` to store upto 4 decimal

Comment: @SureshMahawar Thank you that solved it

Comment: There is a difference between the value of a float and its representation. The precision of a float is fixed in MongoDB, so you do not save any space by limiting the number of digits. Aggregations however will become less precise (think of averages and sums). So instead of limiting the number of digits while storing the values you should limit the number of digits when you display the values.